# How would I go about launching a custom URI intent for each marker within my ClusterManager?

Tags: android, kotlin, maps, markers

I am currently trying to launch a Uri intent so that when the user clicks the Info Window of a marker, it will launch a google query + the name of that corresponding marker which I have obtained from Firebase and parsed into ClusterManager.

I have tried creating a String holder to store the company name inside it, and then adding it with a google query string and passing it as a Uri Intent all inside my setOnInfoWindowClickListener.

(**NOTE:** 'TheNameOfThisMarker' is not actually defined here, I just wanted to give an idea of what I am trying to accomplish')

My Info Window Click Listener:

```
        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(object : GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener {
            override fun onInfoWindowClick(marker: Marker) {
                val url = "http://www.google.com/#q=" + " " + (TheNameOfThisMarker)
                val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url))
                startActivity(i)
            }
        })
```

Loading Data from Firebase:

```
    private fun loadMarkersFromDB() {
        mCompanies.child("data/results").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (s in dataSnapshot.children) {
                        var company = s.getValue(Company::class.java)
                        val infoWindow =
                            MyItem(company!!.latitude, company.longitude, company.name)
                        mClusterManager.setAnimation(false)

                        if ((company.latitude < (circle.center.latitude + circle.radius) && company.latitude > (circle.center.latitude - circle.radius))
                            && ((company.longitude < (circle.center.longitude + circle.radius) && company.longitude > (circle.center.longitude - circle.radius)))
                        ) {
                            mClusterManager.addItem(infoWindow)
                        }

                        TheNameOfThisMarker = company!!.name
                        Log.d("onDataChange", company.toString())
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                Log.w("MapsActivity", databaseError.toException())
            }
        })
    }
```

My Cluster setup:

```
    private fun setUpCluster() {
        // Initialize the manager with the context and the map.
        // (Activity extends context, so we can pass 'this' in the constructor.)
        mClusterManager = ClusterManager(this, mMap)
        // Point the map's listeners at the listeners implemented by the cluster
        // manager.
        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(mClusterManager)
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager)

        // Add cluster items (markers) to the cluster manager.
        loadMarkersFromDB()
    }
```

Although I am able to do something inside my Info Window Click Listener, I have no idea how to pinpoint each individual marker's name and add it into my query Uri intent.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research and trial and error, I found a solution to my own problem.

I created HashMap of **LatLng, String**

I store the LatLng locations from my Firebase into the HashMap as well as the Company names which is of type String, and then on my setOnInfoWindowClickListener, I create a lat and long variable that holds marker.position.latitude, and longitude. I then create another variable called addPositions of type LatLng, and I add the lat and long marker positions into it. Then I just go companyMap.get(addPositions) and Voila!! I get the company String name for the corresponding markers!

```
    private lateinit var companyName: String
    private lateinit var companyLocation: LatLng
    private val companyMap = hashMapOf<LatLng, String>()
```

```
        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(object : GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener {
            override fun onInfoWindowClick(marker: Marker) {
                var lat = marker.position.latitude
                var long = marker.position.longitude
                var addPositions: LatLng
                addPositions = LatLng(lat, long)

                var companyGet = companyMap.get(addPositions)

                val url = "http://www.google.com/#q=" + companyGet.toString()
                val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url))
                startActivity(i)
            }
        })
```

```
  private fun loadMarkersFromDB() {
        mCompanies.child("data/results").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (s in dataSnapshot.children) {
                        var company = s.getValue(Company::class.java)
                        val infoWindow =
                            MyItem(company!!.latitude, company.longitude, company.name)
                        mClusterManager.setAnimation(false)

                        if ((company.latitude < (circle.center.latitude + circle.radius) && company.latitude > (circle.center.latitude - circle.radius))
                            && ((company.longitude < (circle.center.longitude + circle.radius) && company.longitude > (circle.center.longitude - circle.radius)))
                        ) {
                            mClusterManager.addItem(infoWindow)
                        }

                        companyName = company.name
                        companyLocation = LatLng(company.latitude, company.longitude)
                        companyMap.put(companyLocation, companyName)
                        Log.d("onDataChange", company.toString())
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                Log.w("MapsActivity", databaseError.toException())
            }
        })
    }
```

WhooHoo!! :D